# Sodium availability in php 7.2 Azure linux/fastcgi

Tags: php, azure, libsodium, sodium

After some reading and samples I've been trying to use `libsodium` in an `Azure` website.

Since I read that sodium would be part of the php core since 7.2 and php site shows

> no additional configuration is needed

tried Windows with `fastcgi` and `Linux`

phpinfo() shows sodium in both of them yet i cannot use it , as exampled in https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/08-advanced.md#crypto-aead-aes256gcm because all i get is

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   sodium_crypto_aead_aes256gcm_is_available()

```
my phpinfo -> 
PHP Version 7.2.1  
System  Linux 737d7217d54e 4.4.0-119-generic #143-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 2 16:08:24 UTC 2018 x86_64  
Server API  Apache 2.0 Handler  
PHP API 20170718  
PHP Extension   20170718  
Zend Extension  320170718  
Zend Extension Build    API320170718,NTS  
PHP Extension Build API20170718,NTS  
....  
Sodium  Frank Denis  
....
```

thank you all for the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same problem --  Azure support sent me this fix and it seems to fix libsodium issue in PHP 7.3 (7.2 is likely the same fix) -

You need to create a `settings.ini` file and the `.ini` file should include the following:

```
extension=sodium
```

And add the `PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR` app setting in the azure portal to load the `.ini` files.

Answer (score -1):

Tested in my home pc where i can tick more boxes and found sodium was disabled by default. after enabling it all went well.

About enabling php extensions in Azure found this link which i'll follow for sodium and hopefully all goes well.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2017/08/21/enable-php-extensions-on-azure-web-app-on-windows/

thank you all.